# Devise returning 401 but ajax success executed

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

I am making an ajax call with remote form. Devise return 401 unauthenticated response and browser console also show 401  what is correct status. But in java-script code success callback always executed.

```
function initFileAttachmentForm() {
  $('#new_file_form').on('ajax:before', function () {
    // Do some Work
  }).on('ajax:success', function (e, data, status, xhr) {
    debugger;
    // This is Executing on Authentication fails
    // When i Logged out from another tab
  }).on('ajax:error', function (e, xhr) {
    debugger;
    // This should Executes on authentication fail
  });
}
```

Where browser console shows correct response.

[image]

Comment: Please include all relevant code and explain what is the problem?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen code added

Comment: Does you gem file include [jQuery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better solution to this problem is to make an ajax call (`IsUserSignedIn`) before any form submissions and any other server calls. What is will resolve issues related to 401 error handing all over the product.

```
// Do some processing before
isUserSignedIn(function () {initFileAttachmentForm()});
// Some processing after 

//definition of isUserSignedIn
 function(callback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "user/is_signed_in",
    type: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        console.log('Before Send');
    },
    success: function(result) {
        if(result.is_signed_in) {
          callback();
        } else {
           //401 error handing code
        }
    },
    error: function (result) {
        console.log('Error');
    }
   });
 }
```

Comment: This is a solution, but not a better solution. Why you are wasting a server call? This could be captured in original call. What if someone crack this code, and start to spam server by send original form submit calls without checking login?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using some kind of gem, which is causing the bug.
Have you recently updated any gem from this list: `jquery-ujs / jquery-form-rails / jquery-ui-rails / jquery-rails`

Instead binding ajax events to form, try an ajax call by itself to submit data:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "foo/bar",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'},
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            console.log('Before Send');
        },
        success: function(result) {
            console.log('Success');
        },
        error: function (result) {
            console.log('Error');
        }
    });
```